# Не работает код сканирования памяти по маске

Tags: c++, winapi, память

Имеется код, который по какой-то непонятной для меня причине не может найти нужные адреса.

```
bool CompareMask(const BYTE* pData, const BYTE* bMask, const char* szMask)
{
    for(; *szMask; ++szMask, ++pData, ++bMask)
        if(*szMask == 'x' && *pData != *bMask)
            return NULL;

    return (*szMask) == NULL;
}

DWORD FindPattern(DWORD dwAddress, BYTE* bMask, char* szMask)
{
    for(DWORD i = 0; i < 2048; i++)
        if(CompareMask((BYTE*)(dwAddress + i), bMask, szMask))
            return (DWORD)(dwAddress + i);

    return NULL;
}

void ToolboxThread()
{
    AllocConsole();
    freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);

    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mMemInfo;

    for(DWORD dwAddress = 0; dwAddress < 0x7FFFFFFF; dwAddress += 2048)
    {
        DWORD dwVirtualQuery = VirtualQuery((void*)dwAddress, &mMemInfo, 2048);
        if(dwVirtualQuery == ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER || dwVirtualQuery == NULL) break;
        if(mMemInfo.Type == MEM_MAPPED) continue;

        if(!mMemInfo.Protect & (PAGE_GUARD | PAGE_NOCACHE | PAGE_NOACCESS))
        {
            if(mMemInfo.Protect == PAGE_READONLY)
            {
                Offsets.Health = FindPattern(dwAddress, (PBYTE)"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8C\x01\x00\x00\x00\x36\x65", "??????????????xxx???xx");
                Offsets.Mana = FindPattern(dwAddress, (PBYTE)"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8C\x02\x00\x00\x00\x37\x65", "??????????????xxx???xx");
                Offsets.Vigor = FindPattern(dwAddress, (PBYTE)"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8C\x04\x00\x00\x00\x39\x65", "??????????????xxx???xx");
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << Offsets.Health << std::endl << Offsets.Mana << std::endl << Offsets.Vigor << std::endl;
}
```

Маски у адресов правильные т.к. они были проверены через OllyDbg. Интересует такой момент, почему это не работает. Может-быть я упустил какую-то важную деталь, т.к. в сети достаточно мало ресурсов на эту тему.

Comment: Это не "читерский" форум! Тут, на сколько я знаю, нельзя обсуждать такие вещи как модификации оригинального клиента приложения(игры), но если я ошибаюсь и можно, то я подскажу тебе твою ошибку, она очевидна!

Comment: @Duracell Я являюсь одним из разработчиков самой игры (а именно единственного активного сервера, т.к. игре 19 лет), ознакомиться можете здесь: http://github.com/OpenMeridian105/Meridian59. Нам необходимо приложение для осуществления стримов, а точнее получения HP, MP, VG из игры, но писать SDK под конкретно эту цель нет необходимости.

Comment: тогда у меня вопрос, эти адреса находятся именно в клиенте игры, внутри игрового модуля? Или нужно искать именно динамическую память? Если динамическую - то шерстить страницы памяти начиная от 0х0 не целесообразно, если приложение х86 архитектуры, имеет смысл начать с  0х400000, далее шаг перебора виртуальных страниц имеет размер 0х2048 - он не может быть постоянно 0х2048, они имеют разный размер! Поэтому у тебя происходит как я полагаю краш приложения при поиске адресов.В общем жду уточнения.

Comment: @Duracell, про модули не совсем понял, но сам адрес находится в исполняемом файле игры (meridian.exe). пробовал также искать 0x4096. результатов это не дало, либо краш - либо нули.

Comment: Начните с того, чтобы сдампить данные, в которых вы что-то ищите, в файл. Потом посмотрите наличие искомых данных в файле. Потом ставьте бряку при поиске по этому адресу. И где-то в этом месте вы сможете посмотреть что же там у вас происходит на самом деле.

Comment: @Duracell "имеет смысл начать с 0х400000" на самом деле нет, модуль может иметь другой базовый адрес. Поэтому сначала его получать, а потом уже от него плясать.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, дело в том, что проблема в непосредственно коде. Т.к. при выполнении AOB Scan из OllyDbg или Cheat Engine я получаю то, что мне нужно.

Comment: @Purixi Ваш код и Олька - разные вещи, данные в которых ВЫ ищите и в которых ищет Олька тоже могут быть разными, вы этого не проверяли и проверять не хотите. Успехов!

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, сдампил я всё в файл, найти тоже могу без проблем. Адрес: "0x3940F70", только вот что-то мне это ничего не говорит.

Comment: @Purixi дампите из вашей программы, а с дампом Ольки можете разве что сравнить.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, провёл небольшой дебаггинг и выяснил то, что проблема-то в функции `FindPattern()`. Без неё могу спокойно выводить содержимое регионов, читать его и даже записывать в файл без каких-либо крашей.

Comment: @Purixi - еще один вопрос - ты хочешь прочитать здровье, ману и т.д. из другого приложения и вывести все эти параметры именно там, или ты внедряешь длл в приложение игры и из этого модуля длл пытаешься прочитать эти значения? Если ты хочешь вывести значения игры в другое приложение, тонужна будет функция ReadProcessMemory, а если ты читаешь из модуля длл - то можно почитать на прямую, если что с кодом помогу

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов - речь шла о PE Header - он всегда будет иметь адрес 0х400000("точка входа в приложение"), на х86 всегда одна и таже, проверено не только мной

Comment: @Duracell Вы ошибаетесь. Во-первых, ImageBase (правильное название поля) может быть иным: C:\Windows\winhlp32.exe в Win7 имеет там 0x1000000. Во-вторых, IMAGE_NT_HEADERS (который вы называете PE-заголовком) расположен НЕ по ImageBase. В третьих, точка входа к ImageBase не имеет отношения, это отдельное поле. За сим рекомендую вам попрактиковаться в работе с MZPE-файлами.

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов - "C:\Windows\winhlp32.exe" не системное приложение?

Comment: @Duracell это самый обычный EXE. Молчу про DLL, которые могут загружаться по адресу, отличному от ImageBase.

Comment: @Duracell Используется DLL файл.

Answer (score 1):

Этот код должен работать 100%(при условии, что маска и сигнатура 100% верные!!!).

```
#include <Psapi.h>
#pragma comment( lib, "Psapi.lib" )

bool bCompare(const BYTE* pData, const BYTE* bMask, const char* szMask)
{
    for (; *szMask; ++szMask, ++pData, ++bMask) {

        if (*szMask == 'x' && *pData != *bMask) {

            return false;
        }
    }

    return (*szMask) == NULL;
}

DWORD findPattern(const BYTE* bMask, const char* szMask)
{
    MODULEINFO moduleInf{};
    if (GetModuleInformation(GetCurrentProcess(), GetModuleHandle(0), &moduleInf, sizeof(MODULEINFO)) == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    if ((DWORD)moduleInf.lpBaseOfDll == 0) { return 0; };

    DWORD  start = (DWORD)moduleInf.lpBaseOfDll;
    DWORD size = moduleInf.SizeOfImage;

    for (DWORD i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        if (bCompare((BYTE*)(start + i), bMask, szMask)) {

            return start + i;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Я категорически не советую делать с помощью плагинов олли и иди сигнатуры!!!Лично я всегда делаю в ручную, оценивая каждую инструкцию в дизассемблере.

Юзать так:

`DWORD healthAddress = findPattern((PBYTE)"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8C\x01\x00\x00\x00\x36\x65", "??????????????xxx???xx");`

UPD:

```
DWORD findPattern(const TCHAR * moduleName, const BYTE * bMask, const char * szMask)
{
    MODULEINFO moduleInf{};
    if (GetModuleInformation(GetCurrentProcess(), GetModuleHandle(moduleName), &moduleInf, sizeof(MODULEINFO)) == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    if ((DWORD)moduleInf.lpBaseOfDll == 0) { return 0; };

    DWORD start = (DWORD)moduleInf.lpBaseOfDll;
    DWORD size = moduleInf.SizeOfImage;

    for (DWORD i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        if (bCompare((BYTE*)(start + i), bMask, szMask)) {

            return (start + i);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Юзать так:

`DWORD healthAddress = findPattern(_T("meridian.exe"), (PBYTE)"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8C\x01\x00\x00\x00\x36\x65", "??????????????xxx???xx");`

Comment: Сигнатура была сделана в ручную. Сейчас проверю, заранее благодарю.

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x778f15ee in meridian.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x01578000.

Comment: @Purixi - значит сигнатура не верная, как я понял функция выходит за пределы модуля игры и попадает в память которая защищена и получается краш с ошибкой к доступу памяти

Comment: Инжектор загружает модуль нормально. Похоже на то, что функция `GetModuleInformation()` не может получить доступ к чему-то: `moduleInf {lpBaseOfDll=0xfffffefc SizeOfImage=3904910335 EntryPoint=0xfff58c34 } _MODULEINFO`. Вот это выдаёт дебаггер, подключённый к процессу. После этого исполнение останавливается.

Comment: @Purixi - конечно, определяется адрес точки входа длл и размер ее модуля - это есть не верно, обновил код, попробуй другой функцией поискать, она задает именно тот модуль кототрый тебе нужен.

Comment: Я пробовал искать похожей функцией, он показывал либо нули либо какие-то циферки, которые даже при переводе в `hex` не являлся адресом на нужное значение. Тем более, мне не известен модуль, у меня подозрение, что значение лежит в `meridian.exe` непосредственно.

Comment: @Purixi - тогда попробуй в ручную вбить адрес начала поиска сигнатуры 0x400000

Comment: Это также приводит к крашу.

Comment: @Purixi - все это ты тестируешь в конфигурации релиза или в отладчике?

Comment: Компилирую в релиз, инжекчу через Winject. Далее после краша выбираю в окошке краша "Debug Program" (не знаю как в русской винде, полагаю, что "Отладить Программу"), аттачестя дебаггер к процессу, далее появляется исключение и значения переменных, из-за которых произошёл краш.

Comment: @Purixi - очень странно, должно все работать, другой инжектор пробовал? например extim injector, в нем метод manual map.

Comment: Не помогает. Очень странно.